# The equation of matrix only containing A and I(Identity Matrix) could be solved as the scalar equation?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

When I try to solve the equation $A^2-5A-4I=o$ for any square matrix A and its compatible identity matrix, I factored the euqation's left into $(A-\frac{5}{2}I)^2=\frac{41}{4}I^2$ so that the answer should be $A =  \frac{5\pm\sqrt{41}}{2}I$.

What have I done above is right?

Comment: No, taking square roots, even with a plus/minus, doesn't necessarily work for matrices. Consider $B = \text{diag}(1,-1)$. Then $B^2 = I^2$, but $B$ is not equal to  $I$ or $-I$.

Comment: Going further, what you have done does find two valid solutions, but there are definitely many more. Notice that if $X^2 - 5X -4I = 0$ has the matrix $A$ as a solution, then the matrix $U^{-1}AU$ is another solution, for any invertible matrix $U$. As matrix multiplication isn't generally commutative, for most values of $A$ this will produce _lots_ of different matrices as you vary $U$.

Comment: Thus, the $ U^{-1} A U $ is the whole solution for any invertible matrix $ U $?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. There may be some that are not of that form; I've never studied these before. Maybe you should post a new question asking "How do i find all solutions of this quadratic matrix equation?", and show the work you tried and the issues I raised. I think you need some other people to look this over.